# Sorting string using collection.sort in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am a beginner in Java and I am having a problem sorting String. I know using `Collections.sort` it will sort String with case-sensitive by default but the uppercase ones always come in the front because it always compares the ASCII values.

If I want to keep lowercase String in front of uppercase ones, is there a clean way to implement it in Java using `Collections.sort`?

For example, to sort "java Python ruby C" into "java ruby C Python".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to define such an ordering:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (/* s1 is lower case and s2 is upper case */) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (/* s1 is upper case and s2 is lower case */) {
            return -1;
        }

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks arshajii. One step further, if the words includes strings with all lowercase characters, all uppercase characters or uppercase in the first character only, do I need check one by one?

Comment: @Jimmy Yes, it would probably be best to check one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use a Comparator .`Use Collections.sort(List<String> x,Comparator comp)`

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by creating a `Comparator` that will impelemt the `compare` method.

Here is example of using AgeComparator:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class HeightComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        int p1 = ((Person)o1).height;
        int p2 = ((Person)o2).height;
        return p1 - p2;
    }
}
```

Now all that left is to pass our custom comparator with the collection we want to compare.

```
Collections.sort(peoples, new AgeComparator())
```

More on Comparators and Comparable can be read [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703185/Comparator-and-Comparable-objects).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good one too and I can use it for more complicated ones.

Answer (score 0):

arshajii's answer is solid.  Here're the two minor conditional statements:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.toLowerCase().equals(s1) && s2.toUpperCase().equals(s2)) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (s1.toUpperCase().equals(s1) && s2.toLowerCase().equals(s2)) {
            return -1;
        }

        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the implementation here.